# Unresolved attribute reference 'switchTo' for class 'WebDriver' selenium pytest

Tags: pytest

while trying to read a message from the success message popup while writing a test case in pytest, I tried to use the following action method. but Pycharm shows an issue.

```
driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
```

**issue** : Unresolved attribute reference 'switchTo' for class 'WebDriver'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Java syntax, use

```
driver.switch_to.alert.text
```